# PHP convert ' to html code

Tags: php

My string $name = "Ali'Shan"; I want store it into database but the ' I use htmlentities/ htmlspecialchars and str_replace but insert I still get syntax error ' .

```
$name = "Ali'Shan";
str_replace("'", "", $name);
echo $name;

echo htmlentities($name);
```

My output is still Ali'Shan

Comment: ' is not an entity for HTML purposes. It's a legitimate character. For putting into the database you use mysql_real_escape_string() or the appropriate equivalent for your DB.

Comment: addslashes() or mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: Thanks mysql_real_escape_string() solved the problem.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string`, it forces you to use the `mysql_` library, which is deprecated and will be removed from PHP. There are better alternatives.

Comment: You can use [mysqli::real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) it's an alternative like Quentin meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addslashes() or mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: Don't use `addslahes`, it is simply unsuitable. Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string`, it forces you to use the `mysql_` library, which is deprecated and will be removed from PHP. There are better alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Use `htmlentities` and `htmlspecialchars` when you want to insert text into an HTML document.

A database is not an HTML document. You need to use the appropriate mechanisms for adding text to an SQL query.

For the most part, those mechanisms are [prepared statements with bound variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/19068).

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
str_replace("'", "\'", $name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_real_escape_string($str) while inserting in database.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string`, it forces you to use the `mysql_` library, which is deprecated and will be removed from PHP. There are better alternatives.